# "Hechel, keuch..."--what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw this text while playing Pokemon in German. The phrase was used by a girl who had just come out of a cave.

Comment: It is usage of the "Erikativ" or "Inflektiv" - see https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/chatty-expression-in-german

Comment: Oh, I see. So it means that the girl is breathing with difficulty, right?

Comment: @user7606 Exactly. Comic-style way of expressing that the character is struggling to regain her breath/breathing heavily.

Comment: the [wiki article about the *Inflektiv*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflektiv) is in German only

Comment: In english comics you'd read "`panding`" or "`gasping`". Here are some references with smaller sentences: [hecheln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hecheln_atmen_keuchen#Bedeutungb) und [keuchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/keuchen#Bedeutung1a)

Comment: @embert: why not translate the essential parts to make it an answer here (or in the Q I linked to above)? An english refererence on *Erikativ/Indikativ* would be great for the site.

Answer (score 2):

those are terms to express that someone is out of breath, mostly after running (away).

> Hecheln = panting
>   Keuchen = gasping

Comment: Welcome to the site. I removed your sig, as signatures and greetings are against StackExchange policy. (I know it's more polite, but that's how it is)

Comment: I am not allowed to be polite O.o ooooookay... Thanks for the info.

Comment: These words are frequently used in comics, made famous by Don Martin of MAD magazine.

Comment: No. The first [German Mad Magazine](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_%28Magazin%29) came out 1967. The Erikative was well in place in the Barks translations by [Erika Fuchs](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erika_Fuchs) as early as 1951, a year before American Mad got started..